# Need help in DOM traverse using php

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I try to scrape the content post of this forum **https://forum.lowyat.net/topic/3424996** using below code.

```
$rows = $html->find('.post_table');
$array = array();
foreach($rows as $go){
    $post_text = $go->find('.post_td_right > .post_text')->innertext;
    $array[]= array(
        'content'=> $post_text
    );
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

I var_dump($rows) and it's an object, I really don't know why is the mistake. Need your help!

Comment: Why is `$rows` being an object a mistake? What class is `$html` an object of? Do you have permission to scrape content? Normally forums have an RSS feed you could use, which is easier and you won't have to get permission to scrape from their site. Turns out they do: http://rss.forum.lowyat.net/topic/3424996

Answer (score 1):

Forums usually have an RSS feed to help with this sort of requirement. Turns out, the site you're scraping supplies this for you: http://rss.forum.lowyat.net/topic/3424996

We can now use an XML parser instead of a DOM scraper, which will be much more efficient. For example;

```
<?php

$rss = file_get_contents('http://rss.forum.lowyat.net/topic/3424996'); //Or use cURL
$xml = simplexml_load_string($rss);

$array = array();

foreach($xml->channel->item as $posts) {
    $post = (array) $posts->description;
    $array[] = htmlentities($post[0]);
}

echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: rss is not real time